# how can we use await blob.UploadAsync(data, blobHttpHeader); to accept a json request

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blob, c#-3.0

I have been trying to send a json data through http trigger function using c# code to store this data into azure blob storage.

For ex:

{"name1":"Chandra"} is the data i want to push it as an object entry into azure blob using a Http trigger function. And below is the code i have written to push the JSON request object into the azure blob:

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

namespace fileuploadfunc
{
    public static class FileUpload
    {
        [FunctionName("FileUpload")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("File Upload script loading started");
            string Connection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
            string containerName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ContainerName");



            var blobClient = new BlobContainerClient(Connection, containerName);


            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

            log.LogInformation("requestbody",requestBody);
            //Stream myBlob = data;
            //var file = req.Form.Files["File"];
            int i = +1;
            var random = i;


            // var blobClient1 = new SpecializedBlobClientOptions();
            // var blob = blobClient.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);
            var blobHttpHeader = new BlobHttpHeaders();
            blobHttpHeader.ContentType = "application/json";

      

                var blob = blobClient.GetBlobClient("events1");
            var uploadedBlob = await blob.UploadAsync(data, blobHttpHeader);
            //await blobClient.UploadBlobAsync("event_json",data,cancellationToken:data);
            //blob.Upload(myBlob);

            // blob.Upload(json);

            return new OkObjectResult("file uploaded successfully");
       
        }
    }
}
```

This code is not working as i expected
could you please help me with your suggestions on what should be added in the code in-order to accept json type of request and push it as a object into azure blob.

Answer (score 0):

The **[BlobClient.UploadAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet)** method can only upload **String, Binary** and **Stream** data.

If you want to **upload JSON data** into **Blob.** you can **convert** your **JSON Data** into formats like (**String, Binary** and **Stream**)

#### Follow the below ways to achieve

#### Using Stream

- Better way is you can use the **MemoryStream** to add the JSON values into the blob.

```cs
# using Memory Stream
using (MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(<Your Json data>)))
{
    # Upload the json stream into blob
    await blob.UploadAsync(mstream);
}
```

#### Using String

- Convert your **JSON** into the **string** and upload it into the blob

```cs
await blob.UploadAsync(<Your JSON Converted String>);
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61280495/add-json-string-directly-to-azure-blob-storage-container-using-c-sharp) for more information

Comment: Hi Delliganesh,

Thanks for the solution.
It works just fine thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure about the second one? From the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-blobclient-uploadasync(system-string)), I see it's `UploadAsync (string path)`. Isn't it a path, not the content?